# Change column value if it does contain one of two substrings - getting a "Series objects are mutable - they cannot be hashed" error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

```
cand[~cand['Candidate Party'].str.contains("Democrat|Republican"), 'Candidate Party'] = "Other"
```

I have that line of code above where I want to change Candidate Party values to other if it does not contain Democrat or Republican as a substring. However, I get the error

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `loc`:

```
cand.loc[~cand['Candidate Party'].str.contains("Democrat|Republican"), 
         'Candidate Party'] = "Other"
```